# Many onClick handlers that all append different text to one textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

The script basically just appends the words based on the user's click/s on the textarea. I just need some help improving my code further using the `.on("click", function{})` and making it shorter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#add_user").on("click",function() {
            $("#textareaFixed").append("Lorem");
        });

        $("#add_disallow").on("click",function() {
            $("#textareaFixed").append("Ipsum");
        });

        $("#add_wild").on("click",function() {
            $("#textareaFixed").append("Dolor");
        });

        $("#add_comment").on("click",function() {
            $("#textareaFixed").append("Hey");
        });

        $("#add_bb").on("click",function() {
            $("#textareaFixed").append("World");
        });

        $("#add_gdrive").on("click",function() {
            $("#textareaFixed").append("Its Time");
        });

        $("#add_gimage").on("click",function() {
            $("#textareaFixed").append("To Move");
        });

        $("#add_gnews").on("click",function() {
            $("#textareaFixed").append("Again");
        });

        $("#add_bash").on("click",function() {
            $("#textareaFixed").append("Thats it");
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can reduce duplication by using an object as a dictionary, and look up an output value based on an element's ID.

```
var messageMap = {
    "add_user": "Lorem",
    "add_disallow": "Ipsum",
    "add_wild": "Dolor",
    "add_comment": "Hey",
    "add_bb": "World",
    "add_gdrive": "Its Time",
    "add_gimage": "To Move",
    "add_gnews": "Again",
    "add_bash": "Thats it"
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(messageMap, function(key, value){
        $("#" + key).on("click",function() {
            $("#textareaFixed").append(messageMap[$(this).attr("id")]);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hmm makes sense.. I think this is a huge improvement on my code.. marking this as the answer thanks for the response mate :)